# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores de dos columnas de un datagrid?

Tags: c#

necesito ayuda por favor en como puedo sumar las 5 notas y ubicar el resultado en la columna "Parcial"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como llenas el datagrid? intentaste algo?

Answer (score 0):

Seria de esta manera:

```
    double num1 = Convert.ToString(datagridview1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value);
    double num2 = Convert.ToString(datagridview1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
    datagridview1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = num1 + num2;
```

en el caso de que estes llenando el datagrid con base de datos, creo que es mejor que hagas la suma desde la misma consulta.